# Sugestão de palavras

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ao digitar algo no Visual Studio Code, ele sempre vai sugerindo palavras de acordo com as já encontradas naquele documento.

Ha alguma forma de, em vez de o VS analisar apenas o doc em foco, observar também as palavras em outros documentos que estão abertos, nas outras abas? para assim sugerir palavras em comum entre todos os arquivos abertos?

Comment: Você está se referindo ao intelisense do código ou autocomplete de texto puro?

Comment: Leandro pensei a mesma coisa. Vc pode instalar os plugins de intellisense https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=intellisense&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance e esse vídeo pode ajudar https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/intellisense

Comment: Texto puro.

Seria bom se tivesse intelisense, só que é pra trabalhar com Clipper, não ha suporte no VS Code pra Clipper, por que será em? :) kkkkkkkk